# Parallel: lifetime of ThreadStatic properties (.NET)

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I would like to understand when ThreadStatic data gets cleared when using Parallel processing in .NET.

Consider the following (heavily cut-down) code:

**My Context class**

```
public class AppContext
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Person _person;

    public Person Shopper
    {
        get => AppContext._person;
        set => AppContext._person = value;
    }
}
```

- This class would have many properties on it - certainly over 50.
- Every property's backing field is a ThreadStatic field.

**Parallel processing of a large number of objects**

```
var response = await Get100ItemsToProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);
var singleContext = new AppContext();

Parallel.ForEach(response.items, new ParallelOptions(), i =>
{
    // Set all properties on the singleContext for this thread.
    singleContext.Shopper = new Shopper { Name = ...., etc}
    ....

    ProcessItem(i);

    // Dispose of any IDisposable properties on the singleContext
    ....
});
```

Note:

- ProcessItem(...) is not a simple function but a complex, multi-step, synchronous process, almost an "application within an application".  Because it's synchronous, we may use ThreadStatic properties to hold data specific to the item being processed.
- When a thread (*e.g.* managedThreadId = 24) enters the parallel loop for the first time, then singleContext.Shopper is initially null.
- When that thread (managedThreadId = 24) initializes the Shopper, that shopper is held on a ThreadStatic field and is therefore inaccessible to other threads.
- The next time that same thread (managedThreadId = 24) re-enters the loop (to process a different item), then singleContext.Shopper is still the same object that was instantiated during the previous loop.

So, my understanding (please correct if wrong) is that:

- when we create a Parallel.ForEach loop, it gets assigned a handful of threads from the Thread Pool
- When one of these threads has completed a loop, and then starts a new loop, it does not have its stack cleaned - all ThreadStatic variables that were set in the first iteration remain for the second iteration (although we over-write them)
- Only when Parallel.ForEach completes do the threads get returned to the Thread Pool

My question is therefore: when are these properties removed from memory?  Are they cleaned up when the thread is returned to the ThreadPool (presumably when the Parallel.ForEach completes), or maybe later when the thread is assigned to a different AppDomain?  I'm asking because some of these properties may consume a lot of memory and I want to be sure they don't hog memory for longer then they need to.  I don't particularly like the idea of explicitly setting them to null at the end of each loop iteration...

Comment: I'm not sure what problem the `AppContext` class is meant to be part of a solution to but I'd be looking to keep everything far more local and considering `ThreadLocal<T>` rather than `ThreadStatic`. You can explicitly `Dispose` that after usage (or wrap it in `using`) and then you'll have a clear picture of lifetime.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the AppContext class holds all the information that is necessary to start processing the item.  If it were a web-site, it may be information about the Shopper or the Site itself.  It's a "one-stop" shop for getting frequently used data.  I guess it's also a bit like a cache, but architecturally different.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point regarding the use of ThreadLocal<T>, and we may move over to that at a later point.  To mimimize refactoring, we'd need to keep the concept of the single AppContext, but have each property's backing field a ThreadLocal<T>.  That would require us to call .Dispose() within the Parallel loop to dispose of the current thread's values.

Comment: Whether we're using ThreadStatic or ThreadLocal<T>, each subsequent iteration of the parallel loop still retains the values from the previous iteration for that managed thread.  My understanding of when these get released from memory is still not clear.

Comment: In addtion to ThreadLocal<T>, also experimented with AsyncLocal<T>.  Key differences appear to be that a) AsyncLocal unsurprisingly survives an awaited .ConfigureAwait(false) call within the parallel loop and b) the value is null when the thread re-enters the loop (so no potential memory leak).  This looks a bit more promising....anyone know of any downside?

Comment: I don't see anything in the little bit of code you posted that justifies the use of _any_ of `[ThreadStatic]`, `ThreadLocal<T>` or `AsyncLocal<T>`. For transient threads, typically the right approach is to just pass an appropriate context object to the thread, or implement the thread in such an object (i.e. so `this` is passed implicitly). All of these other mechanisms are more heavy-weight and have semantics that don't seem to be needed here. Unfortunately, your question is too broad as asked, and lacking enough context for anyone to guess at the answer you really need.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: I agree that the "heavily cut-down" code snippet does not tell you why this is required, but please just trust me on that.  The question was: when a ThreadStatic property is assigned to a thread used in a Parallel.ForEach, when is that memory released?  If that is too broad a question for anyone to "guess at the answer" then please let me know how it can be made more specific.  Thanks

Comment: The question you think you're asking is answerable, vaguely (i.e. the variable lifetime is the thread lifetime), but the problem is you don't really need that answer. You only think you do. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and there's not enough information here to know what the real problem, never mind the real answer, is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadStatic` is a thread-specific storage space.

> lifetime of ThreadStatic properties

`ThreadStatic` is a thread-specific storage space, so the lifetime of a `ThreadStatic` property object is the lifetime of the thread.

> when we create a Parallel.ForEach loop, it gets assigned a handful of threads from the Thread Pool

`Parallel` is more complex than that. It can adjust the number of threads it uses as necessary, during execution. Threads can both "enter" and "leave" the parallel loop's "ownership" as it runs.

> When one of these threads has completed a loop, and then starts a new loop, it does not have its stack cleaned - all ThreadStatic variables that were set in the first iteration remain for the second iteration

Yes. It doesn't have anything to do with "stack". `ThreadStatic` is a thread-specific storage space, so it is still related to the thread.

> when are these properties removed from memory?

`ThreadStatic` is a thread-specific storage space, so they are cleaned up when the thread is done.

> Are they cleaned up when the thread is returned to the ThreadPool (presumably when the Parallel.ForEach completes)?

No. The thread is still alive, so the `ThreadStatic` property objects are still alive, too.

> I don't particularly like the idea of explicitly setting them to null at the end of each loop iteration

Peter Duniho has it right: "I don't see anything in the little bit of code you posted that justifies the use of any of `[ThreadStatic]`, `ThreadLocal<T>` or `AsyncLocal<T>`. For transient threads, typically the right approach is to just pass an appropriate context object to the thread... All of these other mechanisms are more heavy-weight and have semantics that don't seem to be needed here."

Comment: You refer to thread static "objects" throughout the answer, but objects aren't thread static, variables are, so most of those usages of "object" should be "variable".

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: Okay, so as long as the Thread remains associated with my application (this Process' Thread Pool) then it will retain this data.  Thanks, that's answered my question.  Regarding Peter's Duniho comment, I'd mentioned that the method "ProcessItem()" was a mini application.  Indeed, it's calling an existing application's library whose architecture requires this approach and, unfortunately, I can't change that.